# Indentation in tcolorbox package

Tags: tcolorbox

I'd like to have the same indentation within a tcolorbox as I have in the rest of the document.

How can I get it?

Thanks.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Example with \texttt{tcolorbox}}
\lipsum[1-8]

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,enhanced]
\lipsum[9-14]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

The first block of text has the typical indentation, but that in the box doesn't.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Done.

Comment: A quick way is to explicitly provide the `\parindent` length within `tcolorbox`. `\setlength{\parindent}{10pt}` after `\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,breakable}]` ... `10pt` is a guess of mine

Comment: I think (not tested) option `before upper=\indent` will do it.

Comment: @Ignasi It doesn't work.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It works! Is there any way to know which value do I have to put to have the same indentation as the text outside the boxes?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Ignasi's comment works if you use

```
before upper={\parindent15pt}
```

And find the value by

```
\showthe\parindent
```

[image]

in the log.

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Example with \texttt{tcolorbox}}
\lipsum[1-8]
%\showthe\parindent  %%,---- find \parindent
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,enhanced,before upper={\parindent15pt}]
\lipsum[9-14]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Following up on user11232's answer, you can add

```
before upper={\parindent15pt\noindent}
```

to disable indentation of the first paragraph in the box.