# How to put a background image in the current position?

Tags: watermark, includegraphics

I use `\thiswatermark` to put my image in the background of my paragraph like this:

```
\thiswatermark{
   \put(100,-350){
       \transparent{0.1}
       \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth, height=75pt]{image.png}
   }
}
```

But instead of using the static position `(100,-350)` I need to do it in a dynamic way by passing the current position. I know that `\zsavepos{saved_pos}` allows saving the current position:

```
(\zposx{saved_pos}, \zposy{saved_pos})=(\the\dimexpr\zposx{saved_pos}sp, \the\dimexpr\zposy{saved_pos}sp)
```

[image: current position coordinates (x, y)]

But how can I pass those coordinates to `\put(x,y)` ?

Comment: Can you show a sketch how the output should look like?

Comment: Consider using the `textpos` package. Works for images as well as text. Allows you to place an object at either absolute page position, or position relative to where you write the command. I have used it. Works great. Text following the positioned element will sit above it, effectively making the positioned element as a background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer the more general question of getting figures where you want them.  But to the question of how you transmit `zpos` information to `\put`, you would do something as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}
\usepackage{watermark,graphicx}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\strippt{\strip@pt}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Here I\zsavepos{B} save a position

The location is (\zposx{B}, \zposy{B}).

(\the\dimexpr\zposx{B}sp, \the\dimexpr\zposy{B}sp)

(\the\dimexpr\zposx{B}sp, \the\dimexpr\paperheight-\dimexpr\zposy{B}sp)

\edef\tmp{%
  (\strippt\dimexpr\zposx{B}sp, \strippt\dimexpr\paperheight-\dimexpr\zposy{B}sp)}

\tmp

200x200 picture: \fbox{\begin{picture}(200,200)
 \expandafter\put\tmp{Put at \tmp}
\end{picture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes this helps. I did the following:`\zsavepos{saved_pos}
\edef\tmp{
  (\strippt\dimexpr\zposx{saved_pos}sp,\strippt\dimexpr\zposy{saved_pos}sp-\dimexpr\paperheight)}

\thiswatermark{
   \expandafter\put\tmp{
       \transparent{0.1}
       \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth, height=75pt]{image.png}
   }
} some text...`

Answer (score 4):

Not a perfect solution, but you could use a `tcolorbox` with some `watermark graphic`.

For `parindet` value see: [Indentation in tcolorbox package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200632/indentation-in-tcolorbox-package)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    notitle,
    watermark graphics=example-image,
    watermark opacity=.50,
    watermark zoom=1,
    blanker,
    before upper={\parindent15pt},
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{mybox}
\indent This is some text. \lipsum[2]
\end{mybox}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{mybox}
\lipsum[4-6]
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Before making this topic as Resolved, why `watermark opacity=.50,` doesn't work?.

Comment: What does not work? Could you explain it?

Comment: Despite of using `watermark opacity=.50`, the image is not transparent .

Comment: IMHO it works as expected. `watermark opacity=1` applies no fading to the image and `watermar opacity=0` completely hides it. `watermark opcaity=0.5` offers an attenuated version. If the image is not transparent, nothing else can be done.

Comment: So may be there is something else in my case which prevents this to work properly.

Comment: May be it's a viewer problem. Which one do.you use? Do you compile with pdflatex or xelatex?

Comment: I compile with pdflatex.