# How to enhance the background of a Tikzpicture or a Tcolorbox

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, tikz-pic

I would like to produce either a `tcolorbox` or a `tikzpicture` that closely resembles the following image:

[image]

The following code produces as reasonable facsimile, but not great:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{parchment_yellow}{RGB}{245,233,175}
\usepackage{lipsum}

    \begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[pencildraw/.style={ %
        decorate,
        decoration={random steps,segment length=2pt,amplitude=2.25pt}
        } %
    ]
    \node[
    preaction={fill=black,opacity=.5,transform canvas={xshift=1.5mm,yshift=-1.5mm}},
    pencildraw,draw,fill=parchment_yellow,text width=0.92\textwidth,inner sep=5mm,align=justify] 
    {\fontsize{15}{18}\selectfont {\bf \lipsum[3]}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Can `LaTeX` reproduce the above parchment image with its visual effects; or, can the above image be used as the background for the above tikzpicture? Finally, can anyone suggest a better color approximation to the parchment image than the one I came up with `\definecolor{parchment_yellow}{RGB}{245,233,175}`?

Comment: https://github.com/rpgtex/DND-5e-LaTeX-Template

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86150/torn-page-effect

Comment: Also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/580671

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I've tried to match the color and margin.  I don't know how to handle the texture (the `pyhighlight` color should be used randomly for the background of a node with varying dimensions).

**The code**

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\begin{document}

\definecolor{pylight}{RGB}{247, 235, 205}
\definecolor{py}{RGB}{243, 224, 181}
\definecolor{pydark}{RGB}{221, 182, 110}
\definecolor{pyhighlight}{RGB}{254, 235, 204}

\pgfdeclareverticalshading{parchment}{100bp}{%
  color(0bp)=(pydark);
  color(25bp)=(pydark);
  color(30bp)=(py);
  color(50bp)=(pylight);
  color(70bp)=(py);
  color(75bp)=(pydark);
  color(100bp)=(pydark)%
}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{rparchment}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}{%
  color(0bp)=(pylight);
  color(13bp)=(pylight);
  color(20bp)=(py);
  color(40bp)=(pydark);
  color(60bp)=(pydark!50!black);
  color(100bp)=(black)%
}
\tikzset{
  pencildraw/.style={%
    decorate,  decoration={%
      random steps, segment length=1.1ex, amplitude=.5ex%
    }
  },
  drop shadow/.style={
    blur shadow={%
      shadow xshift=.5pt,
      shadow yshift=-.5pt,
      shadow blur steps=9,
      shadow blur extra rounding=1.5pt%
    },
  },
  parchment fill/.style={
    pencildraw, fill=pyhighlight,
    postaction={shading=parchment, opacity=1},
    postaction={shading=rparchment, opacity=.7}
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \shade node[parchment fill, drop shadow,
  text width=10.5cm, text height=6.7cm, inner sep=.4, align=justify,
  label={[label distance=2ex] 151:test}]
  (test) {};
  \path node[below=of test, label={150:original}]
  {\includegraphics[width=11cm]{parchment_model}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this very nice answer.