# How to Add a Baselineskip at the Beginning of a Paragraph in a Certain Tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, paragraphs, tikz-pic, vspace

The question posted here is an extension of the one posed in [Looking to Insert a Figure and Wrap It Within a Customized Tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/609162/looking-to-insert-a-figure-and-wrap-it-within-a-customized-tikzpicture)

Consider the following code

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\definecolor{pylight}{RGB}{247, 235, 205}
\definecolor{py}{RGB}{243, 224, 181}
\definecolor{pydark}{RGB}{221, 182, 110}
\definecolor{pyhighlight}{RGB}{254, 235, 204}

\pgfdeclareverticalshading{parchment}{100bp}{%
  color(0bp)=(pydark);
  color(25bp)=(pydark);
  color(30bp)=(py);
  color(50bp)=(pylight);
  color(70bp)=(py);
  color(75bp)=(pydark);
  color(100bp)=(pydark)%
}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{rparchment}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}{%
  color(0bp)=(pylight);
  color(13bp)=(pylight);
  color(20bp)=(py);
  color(40bp)=(pydark);
  color(60bp)=(pydark!50!black);
  color(100bp)=(black)%
}
\tikzset{
  pencildraw/.style={%
    decorate,  decoration={%
      random steps, segment length=1.1ex, amplitude=.5ex%
    }
  },
  drop shadow/.style={
    blur shadow={%
      shadow xshift=.5pt,
      shadow yshift=-.5pt,
      shadow blur steps=9,
      shadow blur extra rounding=1.5pt%
    },
  },
  parchment fill/.style={
    pencildraw, fill=pyhighlight,
    postaction={shading=parchment, opacity=1},
    postaction={shading=rparchment, opacity=.7}
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \shade node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.5,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},parchment fill, drop shadow,
    inner sep=5mm]
  {\parbox{0.87\textwidth}{\fontsize{13}{16}\selectfont 
    \hangindent=\dimexpr 0.2\textwidth+\columnsep\relax
    \hangafter=-4
    \noindent\llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr 0.6\baselineskip-\height}[0pt][0pt]% overlap indentation
      {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hspace{\columnsep}}%
    \textbf{\textit{\lipsum[2]}}}} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the output

[image]

I would like to drop the paragraph a bit so that it does not start at the same height as the top of the inserted image, and hope that inserting  `\vspace{\baselineskip}` immediately prior to `\lipsum[2]` might do the trick; but alas, it doesn't.

When I add the code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \shade node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.5,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},parchment fill, drop shadow,
    inner sep=5mm]
  {\parbox{0.87\textwidth}{\fontsize{13}{16}\selectfont 
    \hangindent=\dimexpr 0.2\textwidth+\columnsep\relax
    \hangafter=-4
    \noindent\llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr 0.6\baselineskip-\height}[0pt][0pt]% overlap indentation
      {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hspace{\columnsep}}%
    \textbf{\textit{\vspace{\baselineskip}\lipsum[2]}}}} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

the box I get is this:

[image]

I don't understand why the `baselineskip` seems to be occurring after the first line instead of prior to it. I have not had success by moving  `\vspace{\baselineskip}` elsewhere.

QUESTION: Is there a simple way (using the given code) to lower the start of the paragraph a specified amount (say, a `baselineskip`) while maintaining the image at the fixed location? Depending upon the length of an actual paragraph, I may want to increase or decrease the length of which the paragraph is lowered---and so, I am hoping to accomplish this by a command or two, and not by making ``tweaking'' some combination of numerical values in the existing code.

Thank you.

Comment: don't you want to raise the image a bit more, ie change this? `\raisebox{\dimexpr 0.6\baselineskip-\height}[0pt][0pt]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I defined a new length `\zzz` and set it to 10pt here,

- increase the `\raisebox` of the image by `\zzz` so it sticks above the text.
- add `\vspace{\zzz}` to move the whole construct down, so restoring the position of the image.
- changed the `\hangafter` from -4 to -3 so only three lines cut in as less space needed for the image.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}

\newlength\zzz
\setlength\zzz{10pt}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\definecolor{pylight}{RGB}{247, 235, 205}
\definecolor{py}{RGB}{243, 224, 181}
\definecolor{pydark}{RGB}{221, 182, 110}
\definecolor{pyhighlight}{RGB}{254, 235, 204}

\pgfdeclareverticalshading{parchment}{100bp}{%
  color(0bp)=(pydark);
  color(25bp)=(pydark);
  color(30bp)=(py);
  color(50bp)=(pylight);
  color(70bp)=(py);
  color(75bp)=(pydark);
  color(100bp)=(pydark)%
}
\pgfdeclareradialshading{rparchment}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}{%
  color(0bp)=(pylight);
  color(13bp)=(pylight);
  color(20bp)=(py);
  color(40bp)=(pydark);
  color(60bp)=(pydark!50!black);
  color(100bp)=(black)%
}
\tikzset{
  pencildraw/.style={%
    decorate,  decoration={%
      random steps, segment length=1.1ex, amplitude=.5ex%
    }
  },
  drop shadow/.style={
    blur shadow={%
      shadow xshift=.5pt,
      shadow yshift=-.5pt,
      shadow blur steps=9,
      shadow blur extra rounding=1.5pt%
    },
  },
  parchment fill/.style={
    pencildraw, fill=pyhighlight,
    postaction={shading=parchment, opacity=1},
    postaction={shading=rparchment, opacity=.7}
  }
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \shade node[preaction={fill=black,opacity=.5,transform canvas={xshift=1mm,yshift=-1mm}},parchment fill, drop shadow,
    inner sep=5mm]
  {\parbox{0.87\textwidth}{\fontsize{13}{16}\selectfont
    \vspace{\zzz}%
    \hangindent=\dimexpr 0.2\textwidth+\columnsep\relax
    \hangafter=-3
    \noindent\llap{\raisebox{\dimexpr \zzz+0.6\baselineskip-\height}[0pt][0pt]% overlap indentation
      {\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}}\hspace{\columnsep}}%
    \textbf{\textit{\lipsum[2]}}}} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this fine answer. If I may, I would like to ask if you think it possible to lower the paragraph directly within the tikzpicture itself? The reason is that, on occasion, I produce many of them---so I wouldn't necessarily want to lower every paragraph by zzz; only some. With your answer, I can introduce other variable amounts, say xxx, yyy, etc. to solve the problem. But it would be easier if I could do it ``on the fly'' as needed. Thank you again for your very helpful answer.

Comment: @mlchristians not sure I understand what you mean, `\zzz` is only used (twice) within the tikzpicture. You don't need separate length registers, you can set the value locally in each instance, if you repeat the construct but put `\setlength\zzz{20pt}` before the second one, it will look different

Comment: Sorry. `\vspace{\zzz}`

Comment: @mlchristians as I say I don't understand the comment, You can set the length to 0pt so no change by default then set it locally on any instances that need adjustment

Comment: Right. But if I produce multiple such pictures in the same document (add one, compile; add another, compile; etc. )  and encounter one where the paragraph has to be dropped---`\zzz` is fine for the first; but the next one I will have to go back to the Preamble, introduce another length, say `\yyy` for the second, `\xxx` for the third case, and so forth. It would be easier (it may not be possible) to find an auspicious place in the tikzpicture and insert, say, `\vspace{10pt}`, though I have never found such an auspicious place.

Comment: I am grateful for your answer as it works very nicely and will suit my needs when multiple pictures are in the same document---should what I am hoping to find not be possible.

Comment: @mlchristians I can not  understand why you would need `\yyy` you can set the offset value (called zzz here) to different values in each case. You don't need to set any value in the preamble.

Comment: For example, if I compile tikz1 with \zzz=10pt and later, in the same document, tikz20 with \zzz=20pt, tikz1 will recompile with a 20pt descent instead of 10pt. But like I said earlier, your answer as posted will indeed be fine for me: I will just have to add different length names in the Preamble as I generate new tikzpictures. Thank you again, your answer is indeed helpful to me.

Comment: @mlchristians why do you think setting the value for the second one will have any effect on the first???? There is absolutely no reason to duplicate the length register,