# How to draw a frame with an "external padding"?

Tags: margins, tcolorbox, mdframed, framed

I want to draw a frame around a part of the text so that the margins around this part of the text are not affected.

Below is a solution with the help of `tcolorbox`. I've found this solution by trying-and-fixing.
So, my question is: **is this solution good or is there a better one?** The only drawback to this solution I see is that it does not take into account the value of `\parindent`. This is not important for me as I intend to use this piece of code in a text where `\parindent` equals `0pt`.

I prefer using `tcolorbox` than `mdframed`: `tcolorbox` seems to be better maintained. Nevertheless, any solution could be interesting for me or for future readers.

Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\def\exteriorPadding{3mm}
\newtcolorbox{myBox}
{size = minimal, colback = red, 
leftrule = -\exteriorPadding, left = \exteriorPadding,
rightrule = -\exteriorPadding, right = \exteriorPadding,
top = 2mm, bottom = 2mm}

\begin{document}

Test: This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.

\begin{myBox}
Test: This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
\end{myBox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please have a look at the answer below -- with and without `parindent` -- solution at --https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200632/indentation-in-tcolorbox-package

Comment: I guess you just want to use the tcolorbox option `oversize`. Try `\newtcolorbox{myBox}{oversize, colback = red, top = 2mm, bottom = 2mm}`. For details, see the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `oversize` option, it enlarges margins and the text is as wide as in unboxed paragraphs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{myBox}
{colback = red,  top=2mm, bottom=2mm, boxrule=0pt,
oversize}

\begin{document}

Test: This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.

\begin{myBox}
Test: This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test. This is a test.
\end{myBox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
    

\texttt{With parindent=0pt}
    %\showthe\parindent  %%,---- find \parindent
    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,enhanced,before upper={\parindent0pt}]
        \lipsum[9]
    \end{tcolorbox}


\texttt{With parindent=15pt}
            \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,enhanced,before upper={\parindent15pt}]
            \lipsum[9]
        \end{tcolorbox}
            \lipsum[8]
\end{document}
```

Comment: But this restricts the margins, which is exactly what the OP does *not* want.

Comment: was addressing the issue of parindent