# How to align tcolorbox with margin just like shaded does?

Tags: tcolorbox, framed

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,framed,tcolorbox}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{241, 241, 255}

\begin{document}
    Shaded environment can align exactly with page margin: 
    \begin{shaded}
        This line is red
    \end{shaded}

    But tcolorbox can't: 
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=shadecolor,sharp corners=all,colframe=white!,width=\linewidth, boxrule=0pt, left skip=0pt]
    This line is red
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

I want to align `tcolorbox` with the page margin just like the `shaded` environment does. I've tried setting the `width` to `\linewidth` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Note that the `shaded` box doesn't align with page margin rather exceeds it. The `shaded*` environment should be used if alignment with page margin is expected.

Comment: If you add `\usepackage{showframe}` (which will show the border of the page) to your premable you can see that `tcolorbox` align exactly to the border of the page accounting for the margin.

Comment: As per your `MWE`, `tcolorbox` works perfect, but the `shaded` exceeds the text width, please confirm that you need to get the colored box exceeds the text width by using `tcolorbox`?

Comment: @MadyYuvi Yeah, I want to make `tcolorbox` as wide as `shaded`.

Comment: Similar: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/585029

Answer (score 0):

`grow to left by` and `grow to right by` are the tags which helps you to meet the requirement.

Please try with the below `MWE`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,framed,tcolorbox}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{241, 241, 255}

\usepackage{showframe}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\begin{document}
    Shaded environment can align exactly with page margin: 
    \begin{shaded}
        This line is red
    \end{shaded}

    But tcolorbox can't: 
    \begin{tcolorbox}[grow to left by=12pt,grow to right by=12pt,colback=shadecolor,sharp corners=all,colframe=white!,boxrule=0pt]
    This line is red
    \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

To mimic both the horizontal and vertical, both the inner and outer spacings of `shaded` environment:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color,framed,tcolorbox}
\definecolor{shadecolor}{RGB}{241, 241, 255}

\usepackage{showframe} % to show page frame(s)
\usepackage{lipsum}    % for \lipsum

\begin{document}
    \noindent\verb|shaded| env
    \begin{shaded}
        Environment content.\par
        \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \end{shaded}
    text after env
    
    \bigskip

    \noindent\verb|tcolorbox| env
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
      colback=shadecolor, sharp corners=all, colframe=white, boxrule=0pt,
      % horizontal spacing
      boxsep=9pt,                         % default value of \FrameSep
      left=0pt, right=0pt,
      oversize,
      % vertical spacing
      top=0pt, bottom=0pt,
      beforeafter skip balanced=\topsep,  % default value of \OuterFrameSep
      % restore \parindent
      before upper=\setlength{\parindent}{15pt},
    ]
        Environment content.\par
        \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \end{tcolorbox}
    text after env
\end{document}
```

[image]